# For multiple operations of powers, absent parenthesis, why wouldn’t the left to right rule be used like it is for every other level of operations?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> 1. $a - b + c$ given values is done left to right.
> 2. $\frac{a}{b} \cdot c$ given values is done left to right.

Why is $a^{b^{c}}$ ever considered 'right associative' or done right to left or top down(when superscripts are used)?

Answer (score 1):

Every area of mathematics follows different pre-defined set of instructions, similarly there is set of rules you need to keep in mind when working out with exponents specifically.

> 1. Unlike addition and multiplication, exponentiation is not commutative.

For instance $4^{3} = 64 \neq 3^{4} = 81$.

> 2. Unlike addition and multiplication, exponentiation is not associative.

$(4^{3})^{2} = 64^{2} \implies 4096 \neq 4^{(3^{2})} = 4^{9} \implies 262144$

> 3. If you remove parentheses, the conventional order of operations for serial exponentiation in superscript notation is top-down or right-associative and not bottom-top.

$a^{b^{c}} = a^{(b^{c})}$ and $(a^{b})^{c} = a^{(bc)}$.

Comment: When did this “conventional” order first appear?  As in my original question when order of operations has equivalent operations to evaluate, conventional order is left to right.  
My gut feeling is never from the 16th century to the later 20th century when order of operations began and was universally accepted. But, is a new convention since the computer era, and now we have calculators and computers executing successive exponential operations left to right and people (along with some newer software) doing them right to left.